# Shell Link common dialog?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell, common-dialog

Before you call `CreateFile`, you need the name of a file. You can of course create your own dialog:

- enumerates drives, folders, or the shell namespace
- allow the user to navigate
- show files in selected folder
- and let the user pick a file and close the dialog

But fortunately Windows already did all the UI heavy lifting, and provided you an [`IFileOpenDialog` common dialog:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/example--the-open-dialog-box)

[image]

### Does the same exist for creating a link?

Windows Explorer has a dialog that guides the user through creating a shortcut to a file, folder, item, url, etc:

[image]

Is this dialog a *"common"* dialog - available for use by applications?

---

**Edit**: Also a reminder: I'm not looking to **invoke** the *wizard* - because the wizard *creates* the link on the hard drive. And i don't want it saved on the hard drive. I need the ability to **get** the resulting:

- `IShellLink` or
- `IUniformResourceLocator`,

or the

- Location
- Title

that the user entered.

I need a *"location picker*" user interface.

Comment: That dialog is not programmatically exposed, sorry.

Comment: But I believe you can invoke it by invoking the context menu and executing the appropriate action. I believe that there are examples of doing this, in fact I think Raymond has shown how to do this.

Comment: There is an undocumented interface, ICreateNewLink you can find a description here: https://gist.github.com/hfiref0x/e58711820276fe8b1b36dd51faae59cf ...

Comment: There are other ways of doing this, I'm not going to put them in an answer because they are more work and still relies on undocumented stuff but: A) SVGIO_BACKGROUND IContextMenu or B) .lnk\ShellNew in the registry (Handler type used in newer Windows versions is undocumented AFAIK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the same exist for creating a link?
>
> Windows Explorer has a dialog that guides the user through creating a
>   shortcut to a file, folder, item, url, etc:

Yes, it is the API **NewLinkHereW**

A test (VS 2015, Windows 10) =>

(link created in *e:\test* for the sample)

```
        typedef void(WINAPI *NLH)(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hAppInstance, LPTSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
        NLH NewLinkHereW;
        HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary(L"appwiz.cpl");
        NewLinkHereW = (NLH)GetProcAddress(hDll, "NewLinkHereW");
        WCHAR wsFolder[MAX_PATH] = L"e:\\test";
        lstrcat(wsFolder, L"\\newlink.lnk");
        if (NewLinkHereW)
        {
            HANDLE hLink = CreateFile(wsFolder, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
            if (hLink != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                CloseHandle(hLink);
                NewLinkHereW(GetDesktopWindow(), NULL, wsFolder, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            }               
        }
```

Comment: This goes back as far as at least Win2000 but it is undocumented and some versions of Windows don't call this directly (XP does, 8 does not etc).